# How can I get tab completion with juju in zsh?

Tags: juju, zsh

I use zsh as my shell and tab completion doesn't work, how can I enable it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't already have custom completion scripts, make a directory (e.g.,
`~/.zsh/completion`) and add a line like `fpath=(~/.zsh/completion $fpath)` to
the top of your .zshrc.

You can then visit http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~benji/+junk/zsh-juju-completion/view/head:/_juju
and click "Download File" and save it as _juju in the directory you made.

Alternatively, if you have bzr installed, you can fetch the file like so:

```
bzr cat http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~benji/+junk/zsh-juju-completion/_juju > ~/.zsh/completion/_juju
```

The completion file is generated by the script located at

- https://code.launchpad.net/~benji/+junk/zsh-juju-completion.

I'd like to add completion of service, unit, and charm names eventually.  Patches welcome!

Comment: I've submitted a pull request to oh-my-zsh to have the code from benji as a plugin: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/pull/3166